# Error java.lang.illegalstateexception request == null

Tags: android, kotlin, httprequest, httpresponse, okhttp

Can someone tell me what could be the mistake? 
For some time it worked fine. And now, it appears, then disappears. The error appears when I start to enter the address in the autocomplete
I will be very grateful!!

When starting up, the following error appears on the device

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: request == null
 at okhttp3.Response$Builder.build(Response.java:442)
 at com.sheepapps.domras.data.autocomplete.AutocompleteService$client$1.intercept(AutocompleteService.kt:19)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
 at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:250)
 at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
 at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Below the application code itself

```
package com.sheepapps.domras.data.autocomplete

import androidx.core.text.isDigitsOnly
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import kotlin.math.pow

class AutocompleteService {

    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor {
            try {
                it.proceed(it.request())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Response.Builder().code(500).build()
            }
        }.build()

    private val service = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.invoke())
        .client(client)
        .build()
        .create(AutocompleteAPI::class.java)

    suspend fun search(query: String, lon: Double, lat: Double) =
        service.search(query, "json", "1", "1", 50, "by")
            .apply {
                if (query.split(" ").any { it.isDigitsOnly() }) {
                    sortBy { it.address?.houseNumber ?: "0" }
                } else {
                    sortBy {
                        (it.lon?.toDouble() ?: 0.0 - lon).pow(2) + (it.lat?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
                        - lat).pow(2)
                    }
                }
            }
            .filter { it.address?.road != null }
            .map { it.convert() }
}
```

Comment: Do not post images of error logs!

Answer (score 4):

When you go in deep in okhttp3's `Response.java` class, you will see

```
public Response build() {
  if (request == null) throw new IllegalStateException("request == null");
  if (protocol == null) throw new IllegalStateException("protocol == null");
  if (code < 0) throw new IllegalStateException("code < 0: " + code);
  if (message == null) throw new IllegalStateException("message == null");
  return new Response(this);
}
```

So, when return a custom response from `Interceptor`, you must pass these too. So.

```
return Response.Builder()
            .request(request)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .code(999)
            .message(msg)
            .body(ResponseBody.create(null, "$e")).build()
```

I have create a gist to handle exceptions from `Interceptor`, you may look at [LoggingInterceptor](https://gist.github.com/amirraza/28e46b3aa4305cd32ac2d3b56fe5f523)

Answer (score 1):

When creating the response (`Response.Builder()`), you should supply the request.

```
try {
  it.proceed(it.request())
} catch (e: Exception) {
 e.printStackTrace()
 Response.Builder().request(it.request()).code(500).build()
}
```

Comment: added protocol. there was a message null error. Then added .message (""). There was an error java.lang.illegalargumentexception interceptor.
code
`catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Response.Builder()
                    .request(it.request())
                    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                    .message("")
                    .code(500)
                    .build()`